# alignment requirements when storing the result of SSE operations

Tags: c++, intel, sse

Consider a code fragment using Intel SSE intrinsics like this:

```
void foo(double* in1ptr, double* in2ptr)
{
    double result[8];

    /* .. stuff .. */

    __m128d in1 = _mm_loadu_pd(in1ptr);
    __m128d in2 = _mm_loadu_pd(in2ptr);
    __m128d* resptr = (__m128d*)(&result[4]);   <----------
    *resptr = __mm_add_pd(in1,in2);

    /* .. stuff .. */
}
```

In the indicated line - when declaring `resptr` to point to the location at index 4 inside result array -

1) This works in `gcc`, but is this the correct way of doing things?

2) What are the alignment expectations here, can I create the `resptr` pointer to point to any arbitrary memory location and subsequently store the result of a SSE operation at that memory location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

load/store intrinsics exist to communicate alignment guarantees or lack thereof to the compiler.  If your data is 16B-aligned or 32B-aligned, you don't need them.

Just casting to `(__m128d*)` follows the usual C semantics of implying that the `__m128d` has sufficient alignment.  (Compilers use `movapd` rather than `movupd`, and will fault at run-time if the address isn't aligned).

In this case, you didn't do anything to ensure alignment.  It's just by luck that your local array is 16B-aligned.  If you use `alignas(16) double result[8];`, that code will be safe.

For unaligned stores, use `_mm_storeu_pd`.  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.